# Install latest Power BI Desktop without rebooting first

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I consistently get something like

> There's already another install in progress

when I try to install a new version.

I have to reboot before I can install it.

Is there a way to avoid having to reboot?

Comment: FYI, I've never had to reboot to update Power BI Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Install from the Microsoft store and not direct download:

https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NTXR16HNW1T

Benefits:

- PBI Desktop updates itself automatically (no reboots)
- No requirement to be local admin

If you install from the Microsoft store and direct download you will have two installations. Remove the direct download install from add/remove programs.